# eclipse org.eclipse.jem.workbench.javaEMFNature (missing)

Tags: eclipse

When I import https://github.com/xwiki/xwiki-dev-tools/tree/master/xwiki-debug-eclipse into eclipse (2018-12) it fails to show up as a resource to be added to a server. I imported the project as a maven project.

In the project properties, in the "Project Natures" tab, there is a warning:
`eclipse org.eclipse.jem.workbench.javaEMFNature (missing)`

In the project Facets, there are two warning:

`Implementation of project facet jst.jaxrs could not be found. Functionality will be limited. Unknown Faceted Project Problem`

and

`Implementation of project facet jst.web could not be found. Functionality will be limited.`

What are these natures and facets and how do I add them?

Comment: The project has been created with some tools/plug-ins that are missing in your installation ([EMF](https://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/) and [jst](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/main.php)). For the project facets you have to install the [Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-java-ee-developer-tools-0), but I'm not sure what the best match for EMF is in your case.

Comment: Thank you, installing the Java EE Developer Tools fixed both problems. If you want to write it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project has been created with some tools/plug-ins that are missing in your installation ([EMF](https://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/) and [jst](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/main.php)).

To add the missing tooling **install the [Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-java-ee-developer-tools-0)** into your existing Eclipse.

Alternatively, use the [Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2019-03/r/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-developers) instead of the [Eclipse IDE for Java Developers](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2019-03/r/eclipse-ide-java-developers) you probably have.